# Which layout elements should I use to implement a submenu with an animation transition

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

I'am very new to this WinRT and XAML stuff and not sure how to achieve this goal. For my page layout I have basically 2 rows. The first row is representing my (static) basic menu with some buttons and pictures (about 130 height). The rest of the screen should be used to display content. Like this:

[screen layout](http://www.image-hoster.de/preview.php?file=7d1bdb32080235d01472679bb.jpg)

now when a user clicks on a main menu button the submenu "filter settings" should be move down with an animation. The main content is also responding to this event and moving accordingly ("filter settings" should not overlay the main content).

My current idea to define this layout is using a grid with 3 rows and 2 frames placed inside it. When no filter is activated, I use rowspan for my main content to span over the whole area. When a click event is recognized, I change the rownum of the frame which hold the main content (ModuleContentFrame) to 2 and its rowspan to 1. Then I'am loading the filter page to frame ModuleFadeInFrame.

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="130"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Frame
    x:Name="ModuleFadeInFrame"
    Grid.Row="1"/>

<Frame
    x:Name="ModuleContentFrame"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

</Grid>
```

My question is: is this layout definition with a grid and frames inside it a suitable solution to solve this problem and how can I achieve a "moving" animation when displaying a sub-menu. I tried this with an Storyboard but there the main content is just "jumping" to row 2

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ModuleContentFrame"
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Row)">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="1" Value="2" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really animate Grid row/col/etc... changes. Also any animation that'll result in a layout change is a dependent animation - and has bad performance. What I'd do is something like this:

```
<Page
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity" xmlns:Core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MenuState">
                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3">
                        <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                            <ExponentialEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                        </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                    </VisualTransition>
                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualState x:Name="ClosedState"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="OpenState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid>
            <Grid Margin="0,50,0,0" Background="Black">
                <TextBlock>
                    Long text blablabla
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
            <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0,50,0,0" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#77ffff00">
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform TranslateY="-50"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
                <Button Content="Close" >
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="ClosedState"/>
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="Red">
                <Button Content="Open" >
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                            <Core:GoToStateAction StateName="OpenState"/>
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This way there's no layout change, as your submenu is going to end up on top of the content.

**if you're really insisting on the 'not obscuring content' way**

You could just have your submenu before your content with a `Height="0"`, and animate the height of the element with a `DoubleAnimation`. If you do this, you'll have to set `EnableDependentAnimation` to true.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.pointanimation.enabledependentanimation.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried what you suggested and think this solution could fit my needs. The problem is, I have 5 different submenus to display depending on the clicked button. I'am looking for an approach to separate the submenus into seperate controls to keep an overview. I tried it with a UserControl but I'am struggling to extract the essential parts of your code to it. Could it work, to do the animation and state definitions in the UserControl and then start the animation via code behind from the main menu calling for example a myStoryboard.Begin() or something?

Comment: Sure, you can encapsulate the whole thing in a usercontrol as well. If you haven't tried out Blend yet, it's time: it makes setting up states and behaviors much easier. You could throw this thing together without a single line of code in a few minutes. Some links:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/archive/2010/02/22/switching-visual-states-easily-using-gotostateaction.aspx

http://www.expressionblendstepbystep.com/?content=Chapter6

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Tamás, you helped me a lot getting my solution. I'am doing this now as follows:

This code goes into the edit:UserControl for each submenu. On the main page I then only have to handle my Button click events and call the appropriate Animation. Next Step is getting familiar with Blend as you suggested :-)

I marked your post as answer because it was the most helpful in finding my solution

```
    <Grid x:Name="maingrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" >
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform TranslateY="-360"/>
    </Grid.RenderTransform>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboardOpen">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="maingrid" 
                             d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        </Storyboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="myStoryboardClose">
            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="-360" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)" 
                             Storyboard.TargetName="maingrid" 
                             d:IsOptimized="True"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
```